Sign of the permutation when I show that $\ast \ast w= (-1)^{n(n-k)} w$ for the Hodge operator
Let $w=\sum_{I} a_{I}dx_{I}$ be  a $k$-form in $\Bbb R ^n$. Let us consider the Hodge operator in a combinatorial form, i.e. as an $(n-k)$ form such that
$$\ast(dx_{i_{1}} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{i_{k}})=(-1)^{\sigma} (dx_{j_{1}} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{j_{n-k}})$$
from where $(i_{1}, \dots, i_{k}, j_{1}, \dots, j_{n-k})$ it is a family of the permutation group, i.e. a permutation of the vector of $n$ entries and $\sigma=0$ if the permutation is even and $\sigma=1$ if the permutation is odd. The idea is to prove the property only with that definition.
Note that:
\begin{align*}
\ast \ast w&=\ast \ast \left(\sum_{I} a_{I}dx_{I} \right) \\
&= \ast\left(\sum_{I} a_{I} \ast(dx_{i_{1}} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{i_{k}}) \right) \\
&=\ast \left(\sum_{I} a_{I} \ast(dx_{i_{1}} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{i_{k}}) \right) \\
&=\ast \left(\sum_{I} a_{I} (-1)^{\sigma_{I}} (dx_{j_{1}}  \cdots \wedge dx_{j_{n-k}}) \right) \\
&=\ast \left(\sum_{I} a_{I} (-1)^{\sigma_{I}} (dx_{j_{1}}  \cdots \wedge dx_{j_{n-k}} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{i_{k}}) \right) \\
&=\ast \left(\sum_{I} a_{I} (-1)^{\sigma_{I}} (-1)^{k(n-k)} (dx_{i_{1}}  \cdots \wedge dx_{i_{k}} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{j_{n-k}}) \right) \quad \text{wedge antisymmetry}\\ 
&=(-1)^{k(n-k)} \sum_{I} a_{I} (-1)^{\sigma_{I}} (-1)^{\sigma_{I}} (dx_{j_{1}}  \cdots \wedge dx_{j_{n-k}} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{i_{k}}) 
\end{align*}
From here I think that the result can be deduced, but there is something that does not convince in this proof, note that the permutation is anchored to the counter of $I$, with which, as I can guarantee that when applying once the star comes out $(-1)^{\sigma_{I}}$ it seems to be too convenient, but I can't find the reasoning behind it, any suggestions?
I have made some examples and indeed the sign is preserved, but from here that the permutation is anchored to the same counter when applying the star twice, it is something strange.

Let $u \in S_n$ be the permutation with one-line notation $\left(i_{1}, \dots, i_{k}, j_{1}, \dots, j_{n-k}\right)$, and let $v \in S_n$ be the permutation with one-line notation $\left(j_{1}, \dots, j_{n-k}, i_{1}, \dots, i_{k}\right)$. You want to prove that the product of the signs of $u$ and $v$ is $\left(-1\right)^{k\left(n-k\right)}$, right?

If so, I recommend looking at the sum of the number of inversions of $u$ and the number of inversions of $v$. The inversions that come from $i_1, \ldots, i_k$ are counted twice, so they don't affect the sign. Same applies to the inversions that come from $j_1, \ldots, j_{n-k}$. Remains to count the inversions that stem from an $i_x$ being larger than a $j_y$ (in $u$) or being smaller than a $j_y$ (in $v$). The total count of such inversions is $k\left(n-k\right)$ (why?), and this gives the sign you need.

I don't know if it is necessarily what you say, since that $(-1)^{k(n-k)}$ comes out of the anticommutativity of the wedge product, what I want to answer is why when I apply twice the Hodge star, the product $(-1)^{\sigma_{I}} (-1)^{\sigma_{I}}=1$ comes out, because it could happen that when I apply once the star I get the permutation fixed to $I$, i.e. $(\sigma_{I})$, but what guarantees me that when I apply the other star I don't have something like $(-1)^{\sigma_{I}} (-1)^{\sigma_{J}}$, I don't know if this is what you want to help me answer.

Well, you have $(dx_{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{i_k}) = \left(-1\right)^u dx_{j_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{j_{n-k}}$ and $(dx_{j_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{j_{n-k}}) = \left(-1\right)^v dx_{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{i_k}$, where $\left(-1\right)^w$ denotes the sign of a permutation $w$. So you need to prove that $\left(-1\right)^u \left(-1\right)^v = \left(-1\right)^{k\left(n-k\right)}$.

@darijgrinberg So as far as I can see, $(-1)^{k(n-k)}$ arises from the operation between the signs of the permutations and not as such from the commutativity of the wedge product, could you give me some clue how to prove what you mention, some hint, I would be very grateful.

@darijgrinberg I have thought about why $(-1)^{u}(-1)^{v}=(-1)^{k(n-k)}$ and it seems that the number of transpositions that I can do with each permutation arises, but I do not see clearly how to write it, I have tried without success, can you give me a hand? thank you
